# Flutter WorkManager is not working in ios but running perfectly in android

Tags: ios, flutter, background-process, flutter-workmanager

I am using work manager to schedule background tasks. It is running perfectly for Android but not running in ios simulator even when the app is in foreground. I followed the installation guide from the official docs of [workmanager]https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager. But it still not working.

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import GoogleMaps
import workmanager

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
  
    WorkmanagerPlugin.registerTask(withIdentifier: "task-identifier")
    UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(TimeInterval(60*15))
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyAxACIq4HHNAYK2evOUiiwFFAlNIbNX3JY")
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}

info.plist:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CADisableMinimumFrameDurationOnPhone</key>
    <true/>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Hive Payroll Mobile App</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>hive_payroll_mobile_app</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>camera</string>
    <key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
    <string>contacts</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Always and when in use!</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Can I have location always?</string>
    <key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Older devices need location.</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Need location when in use</string>
    <key>UIApplicationSupportsIndirectInputEvents</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fetch</string>
        <string>location</string>
        <string>processing</string>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

But i got the following error while runnning from xcode: [image]

And while running from vscode, i got the following errors:

[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(bgTaskSchedulingFailed(Error Domain=BGTaskSchedulerErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)") error, Scheduling the task using BGTaskScheduler has failed.

This may be due to too many tasks being scheduled but not run.

See the error for details: Error Domain=BGTaskSchedulerErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)"., null, null)
#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:652:7)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:310:18)

#2      Workmanager.registerOneOffTask (package:workmanager/src/workmanager.dart:192:7)